# Git repository mirror update mode

Tags: git, git-push

I am using the Redmine Git Hosting Plugin.

After I push to the master branch the updates get pushed to the mirror. The repository mirror update mode is set to "Complete mirroring".

There are two other mode options:

1. Force update remote
2. Fast forward (unforced)

Can somebody explain what those other two mode options do different to the "Complete mirroring" mode?